# Use child_process and other node modules with Angular2 in Electron project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I recently approached the JS/TS world and I started studying `Angular2+`. I'm building `Angular2+` projects (using `angular-cli`) with `Electron` making cross-platform apps. I would like to interact with `OS` using `NodeJS child_process` (and then maybe make use of the fantastic libraries and projects in `npm` repo), but I can't understand how to make this working.

I saw that this has been asked more then once, and people just make it working like this:

1. adding in `.angular-cli.json`

   ```
   "scripts": [
     "../node_modules/child_process/child_process.js"
   ],
   ```
2. declaring a variable in `typings.d.ts` (under src). like:

   ```
   declare var child_process: any;
   ```
3. importing in TS file where you need it

   ```
   import * as process from 'child_process';
   ```

and then I can actually use it, in fact I can see autocompletion working (I manually saved `child_process.js` from `NodeJS` source, is there a better way to use it?)

But at compile time, I got:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process'

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much

Comment: I found out that typings for node stuff are already present, but also using import {spawn} from 'child_process' and running spawn, even if it's correct, still throws "module not found".